# Parallelizing Monte Carlo Tree Search

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-tree-search

I have a Monte Carlo Tree Search implementation that I need to optimize. So I thought about parallelizing the rollout phase. How to do that? (Is there a code example).
Are there any python modules etc that you would recommend?

I apologize if this isn't the right place to post this.

Comment: The multiprocessing package is a good place to start. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: This is interesting, Thanks! will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't give a demo code so It's hard to totally solve your problem

```
class MCTS:
    ....
    def _run_search(self):
        ...
        for node in nodes:
            node.reward = self._rollout(node) # rollout
        ...
```

And with `multiprocessing`, you can:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
class MCTS:
    ....
    def _run_search(self):
        ...
        with Pool(os.cpu_count()-2) as p:
            result = p.map(self._rollout, nodes)
        # for node in nodes:
        #    node.reward = self._rollout(node) # rollout
        ...
```

So if you can give a demo code, the problem will be more clear.

And by the way, you can always replace a `for loop` by `multiprocessing` like this:

##### We see this situation: for loop

```
# inp
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
def f(x):
    return x**2

# processing (for loop)
result = []
for i in data:
    result.append(f(i))

# out
print(result) # [1,4,9,16,25]
```

##### Method 0: multiprocessing (what you want~)

```
# inp
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
def f(x):
    return x**2

# processing (multiprocessing)
with Pool(os.cpu_count()-2) as p:
    result = p.map(f, data)

# out
print(result) # [1,4,9,16,25]
```

##### Method 2: list comprehensions

```
# inp
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
def f(x):
    return x**2

# processing (list comprehension)
result = [f(i) for i in data]

# out
print(result) # [1,4,9,16,25]
```

##### Method 3: map + lambda expression

```
# inp
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
def f(x):
    return x**2

# processing (lambda + map)
result = map(lambda x: f(x), data)

# out
print(result) # [1,4,9,16,25]
```

0. for loop
1. multiprocessing
2. list comprehension
3. map + lambda expression

As you see, `for loop`, `multiprocessing`, `list comprehensive`, `map+lambda` is four way to do one thing batchly